# SQL: What is better a Bit or a char(1)

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008

Is there any **performance** difference on retrieving a bit or a char(1) ?

Just for curiosity =]

UPDATE: Suposing i'm using SQL Server 2008!

Comment: It depends on what RDBMS. Not every one implements bit the same way. For example, MySQL's bit data type is bogus.

Comment: For SQL Server, see: [Bit vs. Char(1) in SQL Server](http://thehobt.blogspot.com/2009/02/bit-vs-char1-in-sql-server.html)

Comment: @BoltClock - This should definitely be elaborated and made an answer.

Comment: @Justin Niessner: Adam has kind of done that already :)

Comment: @BoltClock - Details. I saw your comment first. Haha.

Comment: Also note that Linq2Sql maps sql `bit` to c# `bool`. That will make your Linq queries more fluent.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For SQL Server: up to 8 columns of type `BIT` can be stored inside a single byte, while each column of type `CHAR(1)` will take up one byte.

On the other hand: a `BIT` column can have two values (0 = false, 1 = true) or no value at all (NULL) - while a `CHAR(1)` can have any character value (much more possibilities)

So really, it comes down to:

- do you really need a true/false (yes/no) field? If so: use `BIT`
- do you need something with more than just two possible values - use `CHAR(1)`

I don't think it makes any significant difference, from a performance point of view - unless you have tens of thousands of columns. Then of course, using `BIT` which can store up to 8 columns in a single byte would be beneficial. But again: for your "normal" database case, where you have a few, a dozen of those columns, it really doesn't make a big difference. Pick the column type that **suits your needs** - don't over-worry about performance.....

Comment: That's is not the concern of the question... I wanna know about the performance

Comment: @Renanlf: It's answered in the first two sentences.

Comment: @renanlf: tried to add some more performance content - but quite honestly: this is a teeny tiny micro-optimization, I would think other factors are much more important - pick the column that **matches** what you need!

Comment: Yeah, i know is a tiny optimzation and bla bla bal... That's why it's just for curiosity =]

Comment: Digging up this old post, even though a micro-optimization - it's always good to vet and screen new column additions for performance. Even a little helps.

Answer (score 3):

a bit and a char(1) will both take a 1 byte to store,assuming you only have 1 bit column in the table, SQL Server will store up tp 8 bit columns in 1 byte. I don't think there is a difference in performance.

One thing to be aware of is that you can't do sum on a bit column

```
CREATE TABLE #test( a BIT)

INSERT #test VALUES (1)
INSERT #test VALUES (1)

SELECT sum(a) FROM #test
```

*Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 1

Operand data type bit is invalid for sum operator.*

you have to convert it first

```
SELECT sum(CONVERT(INT,a)) FROM #test
```

Comment: You can't do sum on a char(1) column, either

`CREATE TABLE #test( a CHAR(1))

INSERT #test VALUES (1)
INSERT #test VALUES (1)

SELECT sum(a) FROM #test`

Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
 Operand data type char is invalid for sum operator.

Answer (score 2):

It's implementation dependent. One DBMS might have the same performance, while another might have differences.

Answer (score 1):

As Adam says, it depends on the database implementing the data types properly, but in theory the following holds:

Bit:

Will store 1 or 0 or null. Only takes a Bit to store the value (by definition!). Usually used for true or false, and many programming languages will interpret a bit as a true or false field automatically.

Char[1]:

A char takes 8 bits, or one byte, so its 8 times larger when stored. You can store (pretty much) any character in there. Will probably be interpreted as a string by programming languages. I think Char[1] will always take the full byte, even when empty, unless you use varchar or nvarchar.

Answer (score -1):

use a bit. ALWAYS use the smallest possible datatype. it is critical once you start getting large tables.