# Insert data in dynamic column specified by user

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table of language having column `isactive`, `hindi`, `english`, ....

I am creating a stored procedure for inserting new data like this:

```
create proc USP_Insertdata
   @lang varchar(20),
   @data nvarchar(50)
as
begin
   EXEC(N'insert into language(@lang, isactive) values(@data, 'true')') 
end
```

Getting problem in exec

Comment: @lang is variable, and I thing that is causing you the issue. A way around can be the Switch case. Write query for every language differently in CASE and apply switch based on the input from user.

Comment: you do not need dynamic SQL here. Just create a IF .. ELSE branch. by specifying different column names for each language.

Comment: @VishalGajjar: Seriously? If you have to support [more than a couple cultures](http://download1.parallels.com/SiteBuilder/Windows/docs/3.2/en_US/sitebulder-3.2-win-sdk-localization-pack-creation-guide/30801.htm), you'll have a giant `IF .. ELSE` tree. Dynamic SQL is definitely the first option I'd go with in this situation, if I couldn't change the DB design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to bind `lang` dynamically as column names cannot be parameterized, however, `@data` can be parameterized, using `sp_executesql`:

```
create proc USP_Insertdata @lang varchar(20), @data nvarchar(50)
as 
begin
   declare @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'insert into language(' + @lang + ',isactive) values(@data,''true'')';
   exec sp_executesql  @sql, N'@data nvarchar(50)', @data=@data
end
```

[Sql Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0511c8/1). Note the comments below with regards to validating that the column name (`@lang`) is a valid column in the table, to prevent against nasties like Sql Injection. Given that there must be a finite number of column names, I would suggest validating `@lang` against a white list (i.e. checking `@lang`against a permissable list of values)

**Edit**
Resorting to dynamic Sql is often a sign of a smell. I'm not in agreement with the table design, since, after using the above proc to insert data, this will result in sparse data similar to:

*Language*

```
English    French    Russian  IsAcive
Yes        NULL      NULL     true
NULL       Oui       NULL     true
NULL       NULL      Da       true
```

As an alternative, you could choose to unpivot the languages as columns, and instead normalize the `data` inserts into language, after first creating a simple reference table of available languages:

*LanguageType*

```
ID(PK) Language
EN     English
FR     French
RU     Russian
```

After looking up the appropriate language code, the original `Language` table would be normalized to:

*LanguageData*

```
LanguageId(FK) Data     IsActive
EN             Yes      1
FR             Oui      1
RU             Da       1
```

One last point - `isactive` appears to imply a boolean - it is more common to model this as a [`BIT` or `CHAR` enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106166/sql-what-is-better-a-bit-or-a-char1)

Comment: Hi @StuartLC I would also suggest QUOTENAME(@lang), or does sp_ExcuteSQL handle injection?

Comment: @VishalGajjar You are right - It will only handle injection on the parameterized variables, i.e. `@data` is safe, but @lang is not. Since the number of columns is finite, I would validate the columns against a white list of possible columns before doing this.

Comment: Thanks i will take precautions for same  :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this procedure.

```
    create proc USP_Insertdata @lang varchar(20), @data nvarchar(50) as begin

EXEC(N'insert into language(' + @lang + ',isactive) values(' + @data + ',true)') end
```

Comment: "@lang" will cause here, OP is trying to pass column name

Comment: `@lang` is susceptible to injection.