# Creating a win/loss ratio table/function

Tags: sql-server, database

I'm currently making an app which will give win/loss ratios for an MMO's PVP system (I have a specific one it's designed for but it's not important). The idea is that a player finishes a match and punches in some data which I'll include below. After the database is populated, a player could then punch in their opponents' clan tag, the upcoming map name, game type, and team composition in order to get the opponent's W/L ratio for that map. Sort of a way of figuring out what to expect as far as their odds go.

I've got the tables designed, but I'm confounded by what the function to do this is going to look like and how to integrate it. If it was just straight W/L, no big deal. But once I toss in the map and other factors, it's a little more than I can suss out.

Also, a small best practices question: Is it better to enter Wins/Losses as W/L or to set it up as a boolean value so T=W and F=L?

So what does a function look like for this? The table data is below, lifted right from my table creation:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Games] (
[GameID]            INT           NOT NULL,
[SubmitterClanID]   INT           NULL,
[OpponentClanID]    INT           NULL,
[GameOutcome]       NVARCHAR (3)  NULL,
[SubmitterUnitSize] INT           NULL,
[OpposingUnitSize]  INT           NULL,
[GameMode]          VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[MapName]           VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[Grids]             CHAR (2)      NULL,
[1stDeck]           VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[2ndDeck]           VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[3rdDeck]           VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[4thDeck]           VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[Narrative]         VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
```

Decks in this case are enemy loadouts. GameID would be automatically created with a +1 to the ID as it's populated. So at minimum, the function needs to display W/L based on Clan IDs, map names, and game modes. It would ideally also include decks and strategic map grids, but I'm content without those.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Regarding `char(1)` and `bit` you can read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106166/sql-what-is-better-a-bit-or-a-char1

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Nvm, just realized you were looking for a function, not just a query.

Assuming you don't want the ratio reduced, just plug your variables into the where clause of the following.  You can also group by Grids or other factors if you want to add those.

```
Select Count(distinct case when GameOutcome = 'Win' then GameID end)*100.0
    /Count(distinct GameID) as PercentWon  --OR
, Cast(Count(distinct case when GameOutcome = 'Win' then GameID end) as Varchar) 
    + ':' + Cast(Count(distinct case when GameOutcome = 'Loss' then GameID end) as Varchar) as WinLossRatio
from Games
where OpponentClanID = @OppID
and MapName = @Map
and GameMode = @GameType
```

Comment: Boss, thank you. I'm presuming that it will accept true and false from the bit value in game outcomes instead of win loss.

A query gets me partway there, too, so don't worry!