# Performance Issue in Left outer join Sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

In my project I need find difference task based on old and new revision in the same table.

```
id     |    task   |   latest_Rev
1             A            N
1             B            N
2             C            Y
2             A            Y
2             B            Y
```

**Expected Result:**

```
   id       |     task   | latest_Rev   
   2               C           Y
```

So I tried following query

```
  Select new.* 
  from Rev_tmp nw with (nolock)
  left outer 
  join rev_tmp  old with (nolock)
  on   nw.id -1  = old.id
  and  nw.task = old.task
  and  nw.latest_rev = 'y'
  where old.task is null
```

when my table have more than 20k records this query takes more time?
How to reduce the time?

In my company don't allow to use subquery

Comment: More than what? How is your table indexed? What is the query plan?

Comment: Not allowed to use subqueries sounds really strange. Are you allowed to use CTEs? Derived tables? Why are you allowed to use NOLOCK?

Comment: my table have no clustered index with all primary fields. Its a RULES. @JamesZ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `LAG` function to remove the self join

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT *,
               CASE WHEN latest_Rev = 'y' THEN Lag(latest_Rev) OVER(partition BY task ORDER BY id) ELSE NULL END AS prev_rev
        FROM   Rev_tmp) a
WHERE  prev_rev IS NULL
```

Comment: What is better in performance? My "not exists" or your "Lag" ? On big table i think its 'not exists', what did you think about this?

Comment: @Esperento57 - Obviously `LAG`, `Not exists` needs to *scan/seek* the table twice.

Comment: Yes but you use 'case' too and temporary table for your where ;)

Comment: @Esperento57 - It is not temporary table. It is called derived table which is not going to store anything in disk. Using `CASE` is still better than hitting the table twice ;)

Comment: And if he has an index on latest_Rev  field your query may be dont use into lag i dont know :P

Comment: Lag scan twice too (1 for select and 1 for search back), and derived table scan too => 3 scans no? And case are often expensive.

Comment: That said it is a nice method, well played

Comment: @Esperento57 - That's a ridiculous count :D It will scan only once ;)

Comment: I wonder what the performance analyzer would say :) Have a good day

Answer (score 0):

1. latest_Rev should be a Bit type (boolean equivalent), i better for performance (Detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106166/sql-what-is-better-a-bit-or-a-char1))
2. May be can you add index on id, task
   , latest_Rev columns

You can try this query (replace left outer by not exists)

```
Select * 
from Rev_tmp nw
where nw.latest_rev = 'y' and not exists
(
select * from rev_tmp  old
where nw.id -1  = old.id and  nw.task = old.task
)
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer assumes

- You can't change the indexes
- You can't use subqueries
- All fields are indexed separately

If you look at the query, the only value that really reduces the resultset is `latest_rev='Y'`.  If you were to eliminate that condition, you'd definitely get a table scan. So we want that condition to be evaluated using an index. Unfortunately a field that just values 'Y' and 'N' is likely to be ignored because it will have terrible selectivity. You *might* get better performance if you coax SQL Server into using it anyway. If the index on `latest_rev` is called `idx_latest_rev` then try this:

```
Set transaction isolated level read uncommitted

Select new.* 
from Rev_tmp nw with (index(idx_latest_rev))
left outer 
join rev_tmp  old 
on   nw.id -1  = old.id
and  nw.task = old.task
where old.task is null
and  nw.latest_rev = 'y'
```